# How to impose equality term-by-term in a matrix?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I impose matrix equality term by term in a simplifying assumptions in Mathematica?

The following does NOT work, as it give back a instead of 1.

```
mat1 = {a, b, c}
Simplify[mat1[[1]], mat1 == {1, 2, 3}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Thread`

```
mat1 = {a, b, c};
Simplify[mat1[[1]], Thread[mat1 == {1, 2, 3}]]
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However how come does not work for a matrix?  Indeed, mat1 = {{a, b, c}, {c, d, e}};
Simplify[mat1[[1, 1]], Thread[mat1 == {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]] gives again a (?)

Comment: `Thread` only threads over lists on the first level. If `mat1` is 2 dimensional, you could `Flatten` the matrices first, e.g. `mat1 = {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}; Simplify[mat1[[1, 1]], Thread[Flatten[mat1] == Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]]]`

Comment: How come it does not work anymore if two assumptions are used instead of only one? For instance: mat1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
Simplify[mat1[[1, 1]], {Thread[
   Flatten[mat1] == Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]], g > 1}] gives a again

Comment: I understood. I need to use Flatten once more...mat1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}; Simplify[mat1[[1, 1]], Flatten[{Thread[ Flatten[mat1] == Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]], g > 1}]].